# Database table design Issue

Tags: oracle, database-design

I have a table design doubt.

First table called `products_mast` contains

```
CONTRACTS_ID (PK),
AGREEMENT_NO,
SUPPLIER_CODE,
START_DATE,
END_DATE
PROD_EXTENSION_NO
```

Second table called `products_det` contains

```
HIRING_ID (PK),
CONTRACTS_ID(FK),
PRODUCT_CODE,
RATE
```

The above tables are linked with `CONTRACTS_ID`. `Start Dates` and `End Dates` are in one table and product `rates` in second table.

In my third table `TRANSACTIONS` contains,

```
TRANS_ID,
TRANS_REF_NO,
HIRING_ID FK (products_det),
REMARKS
```

One issue is normally the agreement_no can get extended for a period with new product rates for the extended agreement. So I add those details in
products_mast and products_det with same agreement no with extension 002 (for new extension). In TRANSACTIONS how can I refer to correct
rates if I am linking HIRING_ID with  products_det because HIRING_ID gets incremented with new extension. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I follow exactly what you are suggesting regards agreement no value of extension 002 (new extension) however if it's a case of uniquely identifying the transaction per agreement no, what about adding a FK to the table Transactions linking it back to the AGREEMENT_NO field in the products_mast table?

Comment: I calculate product rate for each month and that's why I have start_date and end_date. So if I am calculating rate for March 2011, then it gets the rate from product_det related to hiring_id. So when extension happens how can I add a FK in Transactions table? For each extension I have rates. So what is the best way to identify the rates in Transactions table?

Comment: If you are calculating rates per product per month would it be better to move the dates down to the product details table with the rate. This should then allow a unique link to the transactions table for rates per part per period?

Comment: The table structure could be : 

`First table called products_mast contains

CONTRACTS_ID (PK),
PRODUCT_CODE (PK)
AGREEMENT_NO,
SUPPLIER_CODE

Second table called products_det contains

HIRING_ID (PK combined),
PROD_EXTENSION_NO (PK combined)
CONTRACTS_ID (FK)(products_mast),
PRODUCT_CODE (FK) (products_mast),
START_DATE,
END_DATE
RATE

In my third table TRANSACTIONS contains,

TRANS_ID (PK),
TRANS_REF_NO,
HIRING_ID FK (products_det),
PROD_EXTENSION_NO FK (products_det)  
REMARKS`

Comment: Thanks for making more clear. I have one or two doubts. Initially when contract is signed we enter all dates and rates with extension as 1. When contract is extended we enter new dates and rates with extension 2. At this point of time we extend the actual start and end dates in TRANSACTIONS as well. Do I need to update the hiring_id and extension_no in transactions table? How can I cater this situation?

Comment: Another thing is in TRANSACTIONS table FK should be CONTRACTS_ID of products_det table right?

Comment: Ah, I think I understand now.  If a new record is created in `products_mast` when a contract is extended then the field `PROD_EXTENSION_NO` is set to e.g. 2.  In this case should the field `PROD_EXTENSION_NO` be part of the PK of `products_mast`?  This field can then be added as a FK to table `products_det` allowing the existing record to be associated with the new contract dates.  All linked transactions associated by the FK 'HIRING_ID' in 'TRANSACTIONS' will then be linked to the new rates and contracts.  Is this what you required?

Comment: Exactly. `products_mast` is a master table with `CONTRACTS_ID(PK),AGREEMENT_NO and SUPPLIER_CODE` and `products_det` with `HIRING_ID (pk),PROD_EXTENSION_NO,CONTRACTS_ID(fk),PRODUCT_CODE,START_DATE,END_DATE and RATE`. In `TRANSACTIONS` table I will be referring to `CONTRACTS_ID` to get the information like dates and rate. Do you think it is a good approach?

Comment: Yes, however it depends on when a contract has been extended if all transactions should be revalue at the new rate or if you wish to associate transactions for the same contract against two extensions?  This would be the only concern I would have with the approach.

Comment: When contract is extended all transactions are not revalued with new rates. When rent calculated to gibe to vendor, we take the calculation time and pick the rent based on `start_date` and `end_date`, if it is falling with the date range, then pick the `rate` from `products_det` linked with `CONTRACTS_ID`.

Comment: Ok, in that case when a contract extension occurs, a new record is added to `products_mast` with the new dates, a new record must be created in `products_det` with a new `HIRING_ID` and all new `TRANSACTIONS` records then need to be associated to the new `HIRING_ID` PK in order to keep the transactions at separate rates when a contract is extended.

Comment: Correction, when a new extension occurs, only values are added in products_det like start_date, end_date and rate. products_mast remains the same.

Comment: In the question you mention : One issue is normally the agreement_no extended for a period with new product rates for the extended agreement.  How do you enter the new rates for the extension?  Where is the rate stored?

Comment: Rates are stored in `products_det` table along with dates and `extension_no`. When you suggested new table design I was more clear about where to keep the `rates,extension_no and dates`

Comment: Ok, great!  Having the rates in the `products_det` will work.  Good luck with the rest of the development.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and kindness. Appreciated.

Comment: I have a question. As I am linking CONTRACT_ID in transactions table and CONTRACT_ID is not a primary key in my product_det table, what kind of constraint I could use in transactions table to restrict users from entering records which doesn't exist in product_det table?